# Storing data in Array using Session

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM prouct WHERE prod_ID =  '56hROHySkeFXAjkq41K9'");
$pro = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

$pro[] = $row["prod_ID"];
}

$_SESSION['bust'] = $pro;
print_r($_SESSION['bust']);
```

Help me ,, I can only save one data in my array .. I want to save lot of data . please I dont know what to do .

and what I i have a 20 sets of columns and I want to input something in it one by one without over lapping ? please can you give me some examples . need your help guys

Comment: You start the session somewhere ( _preferably_ before above code)? Then, add new item directly to session variable ( `$_SESSION['bust'][] = $row['prod_id]` ). Otherwise, every time you override session var. At last, I don't know your goal, but maybe some check to avoid duplicate values can be useful?

Comment: Is there only one row in your database that meets the criteria?

Comment: please include the records produced by the query. maybe there is only one row of record return by the query.